# textbox to display value from another texbox

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am trying to display score texbox value as same as money texbox so when money texbox value is 10, I want the score texbox value to update itself to 10.

Any advice guys.

```
<form id ="bob">
    <p>money<input name="money" type="text" readonly = "readonly" /></p>
</form>
<form id ="nob">
    <p>score<input name="score" type="text" readonly = "readonly" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: which javascript framework are using?

Comment: Are you using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4gJX/3/) - I took away `readonly` on the `money` ID for testing purposes.

Give your HTML inputs `id`'s.

HTML:

```
<form id ="bob">
  <p>money<input name="money" id="money" type="text" readonly = "readonly" /></p>
</form>
<form id ="nob">
  <p>score<input name="score" id="score" type="text" readonly = "readonly" /></p>
</form>

<button id="but">+ 10</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var money = document.getElementById("money"),
    score = document.getElementById("score"),
    button = document.getElementById("but");

button.onclick = function(){
  money.value = "10";

  change_score();
};

function change_score(){
  score.value = money.value;
}
```

Comment: it didnt worked, does saving my file in .php rather than .html would make it not to work?

Comment: Nope. Give the `HTML` inputs the id's `money` and `score` and at the bottom of your html file (just before the `</body>`, wrap the javascript inbetween `<script></script>` tags. @user3250974

Comment: yes it worked but there is one problem because there is a button that puts value 10 to money textbox and it doesnt update the score texbox but when I press enter then it updates it.

Comment: do you think ajax would be better option to update it becasue i have so many button and function that add and take away value from money texbox

Comment: Can you not just get them to run a function that updates the `score` value? `ajax` wouldn't be necessary. @user3250974

Comment: yhea true but now its just too late becasue if i had few line of code it would worked but now i have more than 50000 lines of code and i dont think it will work at the end.

Comment: What about cheating and doing `document.onmouseup` ? @user3250974

Comment: YES!! "The onmouseup event occurs when a user releases a mouse button over an element" but i dont know how to implement it to my code is it like this var money = document.onmouseup ("money");.

Comment: `document.onmouseup = function(){score.value = money.value}` @user3250974

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```
var money = document.getElementById("money"),
    score = document.getElementById("score");

money.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    score.value = money.value;
});

score.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    money.value = score.value;
});
```

But you need to add id's to your input fields:

```
<form id ="bob">
    <p>money<input name="money" id="money" type="text"/></p>
</form>
<form id ="nob">
    <p> score <input name="score" id="score" type="text"/></p>
</form>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Thu6L/)

Comment: yes it works but in only updates it when i type on it. i have a button that add value to money texbox and score textbox doesnt update it but when i type on it it will update it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name="money"]').change(function()
    {
        $('[name="score"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

For plain JavaScript this should work:

```
<input name="money" type="text" readonly = "readonly" onchange="function1()" />

<script type="text/javascript>
    function1(){
        document.getElementsByTagName("score")[0].value = document.getElementsByTagName("money")[0].value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so how do i use this i inserted this scipt into my javascript but nothing really happens

Comment: Do you've got jquery library script attached to your page? The script I posted should be invoked within document ready callback, as my edited answer says. The second script should work without jquery at all but the first one is better choice.

Comment: i wrote something like this "<script type="text/javascript">" but let me check your updated answer

Comment: To easily use jQuery you might attach it on your page by adding another script element:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" />